# How do RippleDrawable draw outside view bounds

Tags: android, rippledrawable

1. create a *ripple.xml*
2. set the drawable to a `ImageView`

I found that the circle is draw outside current `ImageView`

How does this work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is about hardware accelerate，see the function `isProjected()` in `RippleDrawable`.

If `isProjected()` return `true`, `DislayList` will hold this `RenderNode`
(see http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/libs/hwui/DisplayListCanvas.cpp#addRenderNodeOp)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way-  put the ImageView inside a larger layout, and apply the ripple to the layout.

Comment: But how to apply the ripple to the parent layout? the `canvas` in `RippleDrawable` belone to `ImageView`